# Redirect rules targeting subdirectories of various levels

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write a couple rules that will be dependent on the number of subdirectory levels present in a url. I have one rule that works for part of what I want, and another for the other part, but the cause conflicts with each other.

The rules and what they do:

This rule would take a URL like this: website.com/base/{WILDCARD}

and forward it to this: website.com/{WILDCARD}

```
RewriteRule ^base/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

This rule would take a URL like this: website.com/base/{WILDCARD}/{WILDCARD2}

and forward it to this: website.com/{WILDCARD2}

```
RewriteRule ^base/([^/]+)/(.*)$ /$2 [L,NC,R=301]
```

These rules should only go into effect if "base" is in the URL

any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: So what's not working?

Comment: they conflict with each other. ive gotten close with this:
RewriteRule ^(base1|base2)/([^/]+)/(.*)$ /$3 [L,NC,R=301]
(because i would actually only like it to fire if either base1 or base2 are present in the URL), but that only works when there are three subdirectory levels. 

how do i target the last match in the group? like, whether there are three matches or two, it uses whatever the LAST one is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle all these redirect by capturing last path component in URI:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(?:procedures|gallery)/(?:.+/)?([^/]+/?)$ /$1 [L,NE,NC,R=302]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your `mod_rewrite` rules.

Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qRtJX5/1) to demonstrate regex used above.

Comment: will this only fire if "base" is in the URL?

Comment: yes please. if possible, with base/ and base2/

Comment: forgive me. i was using base and base2 as placeholders for what im really looking for. i understand your are trying to write the rule as efficiently as possible, so the error is mine. i really want to target any URL with gallery/ or procedures/ in the URL and ONLY if there anything after the slash.

Comment: ok try my updated answer now